# serial port configuration help.read() and write() return -1 and serial comunication stop.why?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I have to create a program in C, so that I can communicate with a device through serial port. The configuration of the port should be 9600BPS start bit:1 data bit:8 Parity bit:even stop bit:1. I am sending you a copy of how I configured the port, but I have a problem, and I can solve it.

I send a status request to the device in every 100 to 200 milliseconds, and the device should response back, because of that I have a timer. In the powerup sequence I send commands to the device, and the device is responding back, but after a few sent and received commands, the sending stops, so the receiving also stops, and I notice that the write command and the read command sends back -1, and after that nothing is happening. Why is this occurring?

Is it because I am trying to read, and I have nothing to read, so at this case I am getting -1, but if this is the case, why I have -1 after write? 
    Thanks in forward for all the help.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    timer_t tid = 0;
        struct itimerspec it;

        fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
        if (fd == -1) {
            perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        satimer.sa_handler = signal_handler_TIMER;
        satimer.sa_flags = 0;
        satimer.sa_restorer = NULL;
        sigaction(SIGALRM, &satimer, NULL);

        it.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        it.it_value.tv_nsec = 10000000;
        it.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
        it.it_interval.tv_nsec = 10000000;
        if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, NULL, &tid) == -1)
            fprintf(stderr, "error in timer_create \n");
        // printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) tid);
        if (timer_settime(tid, 0, &it, NULL) == -1)
            fprintf(stderr, "error in settime \n");

        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
        fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_SYNC); 

        tcgetattr(fd, &termAttr);
        //baudRate = B115200;          /* Not needed */
        cfsetispeed(&termAttr, B9600);
        cfsetospeed(&termAttr, B9600);
        termAttr.c_cflag |= PARENB;
        termAttr.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
        termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        termAttr.c_cflag |= CS8;
        termAttr.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
        termAttr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
        termAttr.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
        termAttr.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
        termAttr.c_cc[VMIN] = 5;
        termAttr.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &termAttr);
        CleanRxBuffer();
        PowerUp();
                ......

void PowerUp(void){
    unsigned char *p_commands,ima,komanda = STATUS_REQUEST;
    p_commands = &comandi[0];
    unsigned char *p_tx_buffer_;
    for (;;) {
            if ((milisekundi == 10) || (milisekundi == 30) || (milisekundi == 50)
                    || (milisekundi == 70) || (milisekundi == 90)) {
                makeTXpaket(0x00);
                makeTXpaket(komanda);
                p_tx_buffer_ = &tx_buffer[1];
                nbytes = write(fd, tx_buffer, *p_tx_buffer_);
                if (nbytes != sizeof(tx_buffer)) {
                    /* problem! */
                    printf("error writing on serial port!!!");
                }
                sleep(0.2);
                bytes = read(fd, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer));
                            if (bytes != sizeof(rx_buffer)) {
                                /* problem! */
                                printf("error reading on serial port!!!\n");
                            }
                            printf("%X\n", rx_buffer);
                        }
                        ima = CheckRXbuffer();
                        if ((answer == 0x40) && (ima != 0x00)) {
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0x50) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0x1B) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0xC0) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0xC4) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0xC1) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0xC2) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0xC5) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0xC6) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0xC7) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0xC3) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            p_commands++;
                            komanda = *p_commands;
                        }
                        if ((answer == 0x11) && (ima != 0x00)){
                            break;
                        }
                        if ((*p_commands) == 0xFF) {
                            break;
                        }
                        CleanRxBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check error number when it returns from write system call and post error no.

Comment: I mean there is a global variable called 'errno' which contains number that represents what is the error happens during your write call. Generally when there is any error system calls returns -1 and stores corresponding error code in errno variable. For more info refer to manual page of write system call

Comment: `bytes = read(fd, rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer));
                            if (bytes != sizeof(rx_buffer)) {` is wrong. read() can return -1, zero, or any value <= it's 3rd argument. Similar for `write()`

Comment: errno=4 on write and my serial comunication stop!

Comment: i send command my device is responding n number of times and then serial comunication stop my program is running but nothing in serial port is writen

Comment: #define EINTR        4  /* Interrupted system call */ my timer interupted write() function ?

Answer (score 0):

You have configured the file descriptor to be in non-blocking mode.

This means that when you write() (and read, for that matter) it will not block waiting for the write to finish if the port is already busy.

Instead it will return -1 and set errno to EAGAIN (or EWOULDBLOCK).

So, to fix this:

```
    fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
```

Remove O_NDELAY. O_NDELAY is an alias for O_NONBLOCK, and this is what makes read() and write() behave like you see.

```
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
```

This is the same thing as O_NDELAY (in fact, FNDELAY is a compatibility alias for O_NDELAY, which is an alias for O_NONBLOCK), it just sets the flag again.

```
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_SYNC);
```

This you do not want. But I do not think it hurts things significantly. It will cause writes to not use any buffering.